# How do I install Ubuntu over OpenFoam?

Tags: virtualbox, firefox, downloads

For university we needed to install Ubuntu over OpenFoam and now have to do some tasks. But I do not understand anything!

-->  We need to solve the "lid-driven cavity flow" tutorial: https://www.openfoam.com/documentation/tutorial-guide/2-incompressible-flow/2.1-lid-driven-cavity-flow#x6-60002.1

But I don't even get how to get there. I pasted the tutorial path into the terminal, but it says, that the file does not exist. Then I tried to download the file through the tutorial path link. In Windows I can do that, but my firefox in Ubunutu doesn't show the website. So I can't download the file directly in Ubuntu.

Please take time to help me, I am in despair...

Comment: Is your Ubuntu able to open any other website? Is that a problem only with this website or something more general?
My Firefox opens your link correctly. Inside the document there is another link, I guess you're talking about it when you mention "download the file through the tutorial path link"? That other link is https://develop.openfoam.com/Development/openfoam/tree/master/tutorials/incompressible/icoFoam/cavity/cavity - check if it works for you.

Comment: That link works fine for me, both in the Chrome-based Opera and in Firefox.

Comment: How are you running ubuntu? in a virtual box, on another computer ...?  Have you connected it to a network with internet access? Please post the output of the following command `ip addr` so we can see your network settings.

Comment: @raj I can open some websites, but not every website I try to open. For example: I can open yahoo mail, but not that openfoam link... Thanks for your time!

Comment: @UbuntuNewbie Yahoo has both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses, while the openfoam site has only IPv4 address. So it looks like you can have only IPv6 address on your Ubuntu... To confirm it, please post what the `ip addr` command from the comment above shows (edit your question). If you see no "inet" address but only "inet6", you need to fix networking in your Virtualbox so that Ubuntu has both IPv4 and IPv6 address (or only IPv4, it allows you to connect everywhere because there are virtually no IPv6-only sites).